# Comparing sequences of movements for a 3D avatar

Tags: algorithm, unity-game-engine, compare

I am working on a project in Unity where I have to compare exercises (sequences of movements) that a 3D avatar makes (using a Kinect sensor to capture data from a real user).

I store an exercise in a file, as a series of frames, each frame having the following format:

```
<frame_number>
<body_root_position>
<joint_1_quaternion>
...
<joint_J_quaternion>
```

where

```
<body_root_position>: (x, y, z)
<joint_i_quaternion>: (x, y, z, w)
J: number of joints
```

Now, suppose I have two files: a reference and some exercise that the user performed, both having the format specified above. Suppose ref file has N frames and user's file has M frames, N not necessarily equak  (the user might start slower, finish faster, omit some moves etc).

**What is the most efficient way of comparing these two files, given their particular format?**

In code, the file is stored as an array of N frames, where `frames[i]` is an array of quaternions that defines the user's movements at the frame i; `frame[i]` has J elements, so `frame[i][j]` is the quaternion that defines the rotation of the joint j at the frame i.

I have considered using the Dynamic Time Warping algorithm, but I think that my particular input might not be compatible with what the algorithms expects / operates on. Moreover, the comparison method must be *dynamic* in some sense, that is, must warp time.

An idea that also might be good is to generate an index for a given sequence based on some maths applied on the input, and thus comparing this index to a reference.

Comment: I looked briefly at the DTW Wikipedia page, and it looks basically exactly like the Needleman-Wunsch algorithm for sequence alignment (something I'm quite familiar with) except with continuous instead of discrete characters.  It should work well for what you need, though it will take O(n^2) time.  You should compute the distance (or cost) between 2 points by subtracting corresponding values and either squaring them or taking their absolute values, and then finally summing these; also you may need to weight some (e.g. body root position) higher than others for "good" performance.